# Passing any type in function signature in Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax

I want to pass a function a wildcard or any type or even a way to choose between either of multiple types rather than just restrict it to String, or Number, or Boolean, for example:

```
myFunction :: a -> String
```

or

```
myFunction :: _ -> String
```

or

```
myFunction :: (String || Number) -> String
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It's certainly possible, but it may not be the best way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you're new to Haskell's type system, I'd strongly recommend reading the [learn you a haskell chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101) on the subject. If you're more experienced, the [real world haskell chapter](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html) might help you more.

Comment: I tried the three above but none of them worked in winHugs. Lets say you have an custom type like Color and its made up of say 5 colours, Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, and White and then you have the function theFunction Color -> String. Now if you pass a different color like Purple or maybe enclose Red in quotes it would throw an error is there any way around that. I see the Either keyword but using it throws an error also not sure what the backticks and double backticks do after the function name and what Left and Right do.

Comment: Hello! I notice you haven't yet accepted an answer yet. If you're satisfied with any answer below, please accept it by clicking the green tick underneath it.

Answer (score 13):

`myFunction :: a -> String` is technically possible, however it's profoundly useless – since this must be able to deal with an argument *of any type*, there's nothing you can actually do with the argument. (It's a bit like getting a can with a completely unspecified substance – you wouldn't eat it in case it's corrosive, you couldn't use it for cleaning purposes in case it's fat, paint or glue, you couldn't process it further... in case of an unrestricted Haskell type you couldn't even *analyse* it.)

If you narrow it down to types that support some kind of common operation, a polymorphic argument can make sense:

```
myFunction' :: Show a => a -> String
myFunction' x = "The value is " ++ show x
```

Your other approach, supporting only two very specific types, is also possible:

```
myFunction'' :: Either String Integer -> String
myFunction'' (Left s) = "Got a string: “" ++ s ++ "”"
myFunction'' (Right n) = "Got a number: " ++ show n
```

Note that these two approaches are quite different: `Show a => a -> String` can be used as `String -> String` or as `Integer -> String`, or in fact any other type which supports the [`show` operation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:show) (including newly-defined types of your own), but you must decide *at compile-time* which type you want. At runtime, all arguments passed to this function must then have the same type.

`Either String Integer -> String` can accept a mixture of `String`- and `Integer` values at runtime, but is always restricted to only these two types.

Comment: May I make a suggestion to write the constraint as `(Show a) => ...` rather than `Show a => ...` to more clearly denote that it's a constraint, rather than an argument? I realise this is more of a style choice, however I've always found it to be helpful in reading a function's type.

Comment: @AJFarmar yeah you've got a point there... I've actually started parenthesising all constraints a couple of times (in particular, superclass constraints), but eventually the “avoid all unnecessary parens” instinct always won. I'll consider it again in future SO answers.

Comment: One major difference between the two styles is also the fact that you need to wrap the `String` / `Integer` using the right constructor in the `myFunction''` case.

Answer (score 4):

Defining a function `a -> String` is easily possible, it just won't be able to do anything useful unless you also restrict `a` to some typeclass (like `Show`).

`_ -> String` is not valid syntax. If it were, I imagine it would do the same as `a -> String`, so you can just use that.

`(String || Number) -> String` is also not valid syntax, but `Either String Number -> String` is. You can also define your data type with constructors for the types you want to allow.

Comment: Both of those last two *are* technically syntactically valid (with GHC extensions), just not what the person asking the question is looking for.

Answer (score 4):

`myFunction :: a -> String` means that `myFunction` can take an argument of any type, but will always return a string.  This is legal Haskell syntax.

With `PartialTypeSignatures` enabled, `myFunction :: _ -> String` is legal Haskell syntax, with `_` acting as a "hole", or a way to get the compiler to tell you what type it inferred at that position:

```
Temp.hs:4:15: warning: [-Wpartial-type-signatures]
    • Found type wildcard ‘_’ standing for ‘String’
    • In the type signature: myFunction :: _ -> String
  |
4 | myFunction :: _ -> String
  |               ^
```

If you enable `TypeOperators`, then you can define `type (||) = Either`, which make `myFuncion :: (String || Number) -> String` mean that `myFuncion` is a function that takes an argument of type `Either String Number` and returns a `String`:

```
type Number = Integer
type (||) = Either

myFuncion = (String ||  Number) -> String
myFuncion (Left string) = string
myFuncion (Right number) = show number
```